# Assign regex capture in one statement

Tags: regex, perl, capture

I have found this is a way to assign a `regex` capture in one statement:

```
$str1 = "Hello World";
($str2) = $str1 =~ m[(.+?)World];
print $str2 . "\n";  # output is "Hello "
```

Why are the brackets around `$str2` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Perl is weird in that functions (which internally a regex is) can be written to understand the context of what needs to be returned.

When you use:

```
$str2 = $str1 =~ m[(.+?)World];
```

The regex function can see you want a scalar value returned and so assigns the value of `1` if matched or `0` if not matched (perl has no constants for `true` and `false`).  But when you add parenthesis, the function knows you want an array, you're just immediately assigning the array's single element back to a scalar value.

It would also work if you did

```
@str2 = $str1 =~ m[(.+?)World];
```

In that case you could get your value with `$str2[0]`

If you wanted to return based on context in your own functions you can use the `wantarray` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
use feature qw( say );

my @a = qw( a b c );

my $x   = @a;
my ($y) = @a;

say $x;  # This outputs 3
say $y;  # This outputs a
```

Making the LHS of the assignment operator look "listy" affects the context in which the RHS of the assignment operator is evaluated.

So the parens affect the context in which the regex match operator is evaluated.

- When a regex match operator is evaluated in scalar context, it returns whether a match was found or not. This allows you to do `if (/pat/)`.
- When a regex match operator is evaluated in list context, it returns the strings it captured. This allows you to do `my @matches = /pat/`.